# rspec will not run - "database configuration does not specify adapter"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm adding automated testing to an existing Rails 3 project that has previously had no tests, and using rspec to do so.

My Rspec config starts with: `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'`

My database.yml contains this:

```
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: billing_test
  username: {{obfuscated}}
  password: {{obfuscated}}
  host: localhost
  pool: 25
  port: 3306
```

When I run `rspec .` from the root of my rails app, I receive the following error:

```
/Users/bdx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:47:in `resolve_hash_connection': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

My development database is on the same server with the same settings aside from the database name. The database has been created and had all migrations run on it using `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate`, so I know that rails is connecting to the database correctly.

My suspicion at this point is that rspec is using a different `RAILS_ENV` to what I've specified, but I'm not sure how to debug that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're failing on the second line of the body of the following method:

```
    def resolve_hash_connection(spec) # :nodoc:
      spec = spec.symbolize_keys

      raise(AdapterNotSpecified, "database configuration does not specify adapter") unless spec.key?(:adapter)

      begin
        require "active_record/connection_adapters/#{spec[:adapter]}_adapter"
      rescue LoadError => e
        raise LoadError, "Please install the #{spec[:adapter]} adapter: `gem install activerecord-#{spec[:adapter]}-adapter` (#{e.message})", e.backtrace
      end

      adapter_method = "#{spec[:adapter]}_connection"

      ConnectionSpecification.new(spec, adapter_method)
    end
```

You could modify the code to go to the debugger at this point or insert a print statement to take a look at the value of `spec`, which should be a hash. By seeing "what's in there" you might get a clue of what you're picking up in the way of a configuration.

Comment: Hmm. Debugging that, I've had a look at the `spec` hash and all the keys are strings, whereas that method is expecting them to be symbols. Unlike a params hash which is `HashWithIndifferentAccess`, this one is just a `Hash`. I could monkey patch it but that seems like a bad solution. Perhaps there's a setting I can change in a YAML parser which will cause it to either create it as `HashWithIndifferentAccess` or to just create them with symbols?

Comment: Well... I could have paid attention to what was going on. symbolize_keys should be fixing this issue. More investigation required.

Comment: Well, I didn't change anything else except adding and removing the debugging (have confirmed against another computer with same version of rails), it's working now. Hash of the file is the same on both computers, so I don't know where this was going awry.